# boost::signal and std::bind confusion, should I try something else?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can send messages to other objects in C++. For example when an object collides with another object, it will send out a message that there was a collision that occured. I'm trying to use boost:signal's, but they don't seem to be exactly what I want, unless I'm just using them in the wrong manner.

Here's the main reason:

I don't really understand is why this code still works even known that the object I allocated on the stack has been destroyed...

```
class SomeClass
{
public:

   void doSomething()
   {
      std::cout << "Testing\n";
   }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     boost::signal<void ()> sig;


     {
           SomeClass obj;
           sig.connect(std::bind(&SomeClass::doSomething, &obj));
     }

     sig();
}
```

Okay so that code outputs:

```
Testing
```

Why does it still work? Shouldn't I get some sort of run-time error or it not call the method at all? I don't really want that to actually happen, I want the connection to be lost as soon as the object is destroyed.

I was thinking of sending messages another way, perhaps Objective-C style using their type of delegates, where you would inherit from a class to have a message sent to you. But then again, it seems to lead to me for some confusion, such as if I want multiple delegates I would have an array of delegate pointers, and if a delegate gets destroyed I would have to remove it from that array... Which could cause some confusion.

e.g.

```
class ColliderDelegate
{
public:

    virtual ~ColliderDelegate() {}

    virtual void onCollisionEnter(Collider* sender, Collider* withWho) = 0;
    virtual void onCollisionExit(Collider* sender, Collider* withWho) = 0;
    virtual void onCollisionStay(Collider* sender, Collider* withWho) = 0;

private:

    // I would have to have an array of Collider's that this object is connected to,
    // so it can detatch itself when it's destroyed...
 };

 class Collider
 {
 public:
    void add(ColliderDelegate* delegate);
    void remove(ColliderDelegate* delegate);


    void checkForCollisionWith(Collider*);

 private:

     // I would have to have an array of ColliderDelegate's that this object
     // needs to send information to.
 };
```

Can anyone suggest how I could implement what I want to do? I'm really confused on what I should do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal slot in your example is a non-virtual member function, which doesn't access any object members. Non-virtual function address is resolved in compile-time, `this` pointer is not needed here -- so there's no reason for crash.

On the other hand, you could use singal "tracking" feature to disconnect the slot automatically. See the following: tracking in [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id3162121); tracking in [Boost.Signal2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.connection-management).

Comment: Thank you, boost::signals2::trackable is what I was looking for. However, having my library requiring to use boost seems to be quite ugly/not good to do?... According to my programmer friends. Main reason being the size of the library. But, since I really need to use boost, I'll be using it. Unless it's a bad idea?

Comment: @miguel.martin note that if you use Signals2 you don't have to implement `trackable`, instead you can pass a `weak_ptr`. As for the consideration about use or not use Boost in general due to some extra Kb - well, I don't know your specific requirement and coding guidelines, but in general, this kind of reasoning can lead us to not use STL and C++ Standard library at all, and perhaps even to not use the CRT with all its overhead...

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it still work?

It's actually Undefined Behavior because `doSomething()` is being called on a destructed object. (To see this, add a print statement to the destructor.) When you ran the program, "Testing" was printed to the screen, but the program could have crashed.

What you might consider is adding a [`connection`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/signals/connection.html) member to `SomeClass`. This way, in the `SomeClass` destructor you could disconnect the signal–slot connection.

Comment: The program didn't actually crash what-so-ever, and I ran it countless of times. And it still worked, no complaints. connection does seem good, but trackable is what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: @miguel.martin: The thing about UB is that a program invoking it can do anything. It can run as expected, crash, enter an infinite loop, exec nethack, or many other things, and possibly not consistently. See [Contest: Craziest Compiler Output due to Undefined Behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/759).

Answer (score 0):

To answer at least some of your questions:

> Why does it still work? Shouldn't I get some sort of run-time error or it not call the method at all?

I guess you are just lucky. You object gets destroyed nevertheless you can still call methods on it. It is undefined behaviour but in your case it does not crash.

You are not very specific on what problem you want to solve. So it is difficult to tell what is the best solution.
For your delegate approach take a look at `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`. You can hold arrays of `std::weak_ptr` and call your delegates through those.

Or maybe `boost::signal` is the right choice. Have a look at [scoped connections](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#id3174728).

Comment: I am making a Game Engine/Library. I wanted a way of having call-backs on my objects, and I wanted it to work generically. The only downside that I could think of with using the Obj-C delegate way is removing it from the parent object (the object that would notify the delegate). I would most likely have to have a base class and would have to use templates (in order for it to not pass in the base class type when adding a delegate) which would just cause a lot more confusion than was necessary. So it seems like I'll be using boost::signal's.